# I was given an opportunity to \ the opportunity to

Tags: articles

From a document I've been proofreading:

> The Medical officer or the Responsible medical specialist has provided me with **the** opportunity to ask questions about the Treatment.

Should it not be **an** opportunity? Or would the use of **an** indicate only a single chance, whereas the use of **the** would indicate some opportunity in general, on a number of occasions?

Is the use of **the** grammatical here? The "opportunity to ask questions about the Treatment" was not mentioned previously in the document, so I'm unsure.

Comment: It's one of those examples in which both **an** and **the** are legitimate. In this case, **an** sounds more specific - possibly to time/date/place. **The** sounds more like approval of a request in principle. I'd stick to **the**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is acceptable. It is both a specific opportunity (which makes the definite article appropriate) but possibly also one of many past or present opportunities (making the indefinite article also appropriate).

Consider as an example:

- "Thank you for sending me **a** letter"
- "Thank you for **the** letter you sent me"

In this example, you are referring to a specific letter, but as it may not be the only letter the person has sent you or the only letter you have received, either article works.